# Xcode 6 Sprite kit - How to implement "initwithsize"

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm relatively new to SpriteKit and have encountered some issues since upgrading to Xcode 6.

Originally when I created projects, I entered any methods into "initWithSize".

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {  


}
return self;
}
```

When starting a project in Xcode 6, that no longer seems to be the default and is instead replaced with:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {}
```

When trying to apply initwithsize, it just doesn't work, or doesn't load sprite nodes I put inside it. Even when attempting to create new files, I'm no longer presented with a .m and a .h file. I have a selection of other options, none of which are .h/.m.

So 
1) How do I continue coding how I previous did with initwithsize?
2) What's the deal with creating new files, can I not create .m/.h classes anymore?

Any information regarding these would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the scene is created in a different way then it was in previous Xcode versions. Now, instead of the scene being created manually in the view controller using initWithSize:, the scene is unarchived using the method unarchiveFromFile: which comes in the template (probably GameViewController.m). Because of this, initWithSize: won't be called. You need to use initWithCoder: instead.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        // stuff
    }

    return self;
}
```

And as far as the second part of your question goes, that's just how it is in Xcode 6. You can still create new files, there just aren't options for templates for things like categories/etc anymore.

Comment: Hi mate, thank you for such a rapid response. This has thrown me off quite a bit. I just got started with spritekit and started getting familiar with stuff. Then this happens... So initwithsize has been completely abandoned. If I have a CGSize method, how would this get called? Thanks again, massively appreciated

Comment: @MegaTron It hasn't been abandoned, it's still there. In your case, it's just no longer being called by default because the template is configured in a different way. If you take a look at the view controller files in a new template, and in one of your older projects you'll be able to see some of the differences. In this case, the important one is that the scene used to be initialized something like this `GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:skView.bounds.size];` and now, the method I mentioned in my answer unarchives the scene from your .sks file and creates it that way.

Comment: Thanks again, I noticed. It seems it's unarchiving it from an sks file. Whenever I try to add a cgsize method, it doesn't recognise "size". How do I get around that? Secondly, for every new class I created for a new scene, do I need an associated .sks file to go with it? Thanks again, seriously appreciate your time

Comment: @MegaTron You should only be overriding and implementing the initWithSize: method in scenes which you create with that initializer. In scenes that are unarchived, you need to use initWithCoder:. And no, you don't have to create a .sks for every scene, or any scene for that matter. They're just meant to be convenient is all. If you don't like using them, you could even delete the default one in the template and rebuild the scene programmatically (as seen in older templates).

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll give this a shot. Appreciate your time with this.

Comment: Hi, I'm late to the party but can either of you recommend a good resource for learning Xcode 6 and SpriteKit with Objective-C? @0x7fffffff?